# How do I indicate the position of the occurrence of a number in an array VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Search Button: This button should determine how many times did the number specified in a text box was entered. Additional indicate the position of the occurrence

This is how I have written my code but it does not show the position of the occurrence in an array:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim value As Integer = txbValues.Text()
    For Each num As Integer In numbers
        If num = value Then count = count + 1
    Next
    txbOccurances.Text = count

    Dim index0 As Integer = Array.IndexOf(numbers, value)
    Dim index1 As Integer = Array.LastIndexOf(numbers, value)


    txbPosition.Text = index0 & " " & index1
End Sub
```

The array that I am searching in is numbers(4). The program should be something like as shown below:

[image]

Comment: One way would be to create a list at the beginning of the method and if a number occurs, add the current index. after the loop, add all the items in the list to a string with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code actually works for the example you've given. The problem though is it will only work if there are two or less occurrences of the number in the array. If you get beyond that it will only find the first and last occurrence.

Instead you can maintain a list of all the indexes you've found which contain a matching number - you can do this during the existing loop you make to test the values.

Here is sample code which will run in a console application, to demonstrate the idea...you can replace the "numbers" array and "value" integer with your real inputs from the user, and replace the Console writes with code to populate your textboxes.

```
Dim numbers() as Integer = {1, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1} 'array to be searched
Dim value As Integer = 1 'number to search for

Dim index = 0
Dim indexes As New List(Of Integer)

For Each num As Integer In numbers
    If num = value Then 
        indexes.Add(index)
    End If
    index += 1
Next

Console.WriteLine("Occurences: " & indexes.Count)
Console.Write("Indexes: ")

For Each ind as Integer In indexes
    Console.Write(ind & " ")
Next
```

This will output:

```
Occurences: 3
Indexes: 0 1 5
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Array.IndexOf` method let's you specify the index from which to start searching so, each time you find an occurrence, you can start searching again from the next index:

```
Private Function GetIndexes(array As Integer(), value As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim indexes As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim startIndex = 0
    Dim index As Integer

    Do
        index = System.Array.IndexOf(array, value, startIndex)

        If index = -1 Then
            'No more occurrences found.
            Exit Do
        End If

        indexes.Add(index)

        startIndex = index + 1
    Loop Until startIndex = array.Length

    Return indexes.ToArray()
End Function
```

E.g.

```
Dim array = {0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 1, 9}
Dim value = 1

Dim indexes = GetIndexes(array, value)

Console.WriteLine("Occurrences: " & indexes.Length)
Console.WriteLine("Indexes: " & String.Join(" ", indexes))
```

Answer (score 0):

My variation on ADyson's program:

```
    Dim numbers() As Integer = {1, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1} 'array to be searched
    Dim value As Integer = 1 'number to search for

    Dim index As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

    For Each num As Integer In numbers
        If Not index.ContainsKey(num) Then
            index.Add(num, 1)
        Else
            index(num) += 1
        End If
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Occurences: " & index(value))
    Console.Write("Indexes: ")

    For i = 0 To numbers.Count - 1
        If numbers(i) = value Then
            Console.Write(i & " ")
        End If
    Next
```